# Not able to push it from eclipse to github : 407 proxy authentication required

Tags: eclipse, github, proxy, eclipse-neon

i am not able to communicate to git hub through eclipse, my PC is behind the corporate proxy.
    i have tried all the solutions like

```
 1. set proxy under windows--> preferences-->general settings-->Network settings
 2. under .gitconfig set the proxy
 3. uploading ssl certificate related to github to the configuration file
 4. making http.sslVerfi = false in configurations
but no luck :-(
please find the error details

eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400
java.version=1.8.0_121
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.egit.ui
Error
Wed Apr 05 12:23:30 IST 2017
https://github.com/ZaheerFreeLancerAdmin/SampleServices.git: 407 Proxy Authentication Required

org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/ZaheerFreeLancerAdmin/SampleServices.git: 407 Proxy Authentication Required
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.ListRemoteOperation.run(ListRemoteOperation.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.components.RefContentAssistProvider$1.run(RefContentAssistProvider.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/ZaheerFreeLancerAdmin/SampleServices.git: 407 Proxy Authentication Required
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:198)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: adding to the above content, git hub GUI working without any issues. i am able to push it from my windows machine